# Three random variables equation

Tags: probability, covariance, variance

Given the random variables X,Y,Z have the same distribution and fulfil the following equalities: $$Var(X+Y+Z)=21,Cov(X,Y)=Cov(Y,Z)=Cov(Z,X)=1$$ Find $VarX$  and $Var(X+Y)$. I am lost with this question how it should be approached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Var(X+Y+Z)=Var(X)+Var(Y)+Var(Z)+2Cov(X,Y)+2Cov(X,Z)+2Cov(Y,Z)$$
And since X, Y, and Z have the same distribution
$$Var(X+Y+Z)=3Var(X)+2Cov(X,Y)+2Cov(X,Z)+2Cov(Y,Z)$$

Comment: ok, but what about $Var(X+Y)$?

Comment: @mkropkowski This answer allows you to find $\text{Var}(X)$. Now write out $\text{Var}(X+Y)$ (as is done in the answer even for $\text{Var}(X+Y+Z)$) and substitute the known values.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

- $\text{Var}(U)=\text{Cov}(U,U)$.
- $\text{Cov}$ is symmetric and bilinear.